# Backup certain tables in MySQL

Tags: mysql, backup

Is it possible to take backup of certain table in mysql? Suppose I have 10 tables, and I want to take a backup of 8 tables through one command.

How can I do this?

Comment: @Mat - Is mysqldump the only way to backup tables in MySQL? If not, this question should stand as a more general version of what you linked to.

Comment: @NickChammas: that's the "built-in" backup tool that comes with the database itself. (There are of course a host of third-party backup solutions.)

Answer (score 0):

```
mysqldump -u username -p databasename table1 table2 table3
```

or

`mysqldump --opt -u username -p databasename table1 table2 table3`

Answer (score 0):

Either you can backup the required tables only in you dump by following command

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword databasename tabletoinclude1 tabletoinclude2... table2include8 > location/fileName.sql
```

Or you can exclude certain tables from dump by ignore-table option.

```
mysqldump -uuser -ppassword --ignore-table=db_name.table9 --ignore-table=db_name.table10 db_name > location\fileName.sql
```